# Copy Specific Rows and Columns from a .csv into .xlsx

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am extremely new at programming so this is gonna be rough lol, HOWEVER, I am a turtle scientist, so all of your patience and excellent advice will contribute to turtle conservation ^_^

SO, I have a .csv with one of several turtle species in column A and UTM coordinates in columns B (Northings) and C (Eastings). I need to take the rows for certain species (for example every row where column A is SPTU [spotted turtle fyi]) then save all of those rows in a pre-existing .csv, overwriting all of the old coordinates. Here's what I've got so far, I'm using PyCharm and Python 3.somethin:

for wsurvey-20150630.csv in glob.glob("c:/Users/Vito/Desktop/GIS/Latitudes and Longitudes/wsurvey/wsurvey-20150630.csv"):

```
(f_path, f_name) = os.path.split(wsurvey-20150630.csv)
(f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
spamReader = csv.reader(open(wsurvey-20150630.csv, 'rb'))
for row in "wsurvey-20150630latlon.csv":
if "SPTU" in row:
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
```

wb.save("c:/Users/Vito/Desktop/GIS/UTM Coordinates/SPTU UTM Coordinates.csv")

So that's basically just a bunch of code that I copy-pasted off of tutorials and whatnot and tried to make work, er it doesn't work and is probably horribly, horribly wrong. Please think of the poor, tiny, helpless turtles.

The coordinates in the updated .csv will then be read by a QGIS map. The idea is that the map will be automatically updated once per day with new turtle coordinates; wetlands around turtle coordinates will be protected. We work with six species, five of which are at risk, of which one species is endangered and one is threatened. Help us save the turtles!

Comment: Hi Vito, are you able to edit your question to add a couple of sample lines from your CSV file? This would help. Also when you say it doesn't work, do you get any error messages? If so, please add those too, thanks.

Comment: Also, you appear to be trying to write your output using an Excel library? Do you need it in Excel format (which version)? Or simply another textual CSV file?

Comment: You can also import csv into excel and use excel equations for this

Comment: Here are some sample lines from my .csv, corodinates for American Toad captures: AMTO,4972096.701,626666.7414; AMTO,4959785.576,634861.6409; AMTO,4979348.076,624486.556. I need another .csv, well more specifically I need the current .csv being read by QGIS to be overwriten with the updated coordinates, I think the answer below has answered my question just need to try implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offense, but your code is insanely disorganized XD. Python is really easy to program in for these kinds of operations.

If you want to open one file for reading and another or writing, I recommend using this (THIS ONLY WORKS FOR CSV OR OTHER TEXT FILES. NOT MICROSOFT EXCEL.)

Keep in mind this will overwrite the file.

```
import csv

open("writefile.csv", "w").close() #Deletes everything in the file. Backspace this if you don't want the file contents deleted. 

with open("readfile.csv", "r") as r, open("writefile.csv", "a") as w: 
    reader = csv.reader(r, lineterminator = "\n")
    writer = csv.writer(w, lineterminator = "\n")

    for row in reader:
        if "SPTU" in row: #"SPTU" Has to be the entire value of the column. Please comment if you want to see if one of the columns CONTAINS "SPTU
            w.writerow(row)
```

For excel, it is best to install a specific python module on your computer first. Please find your Python folder (For example, I have Python34 because I am using Python 3.4). Now, copy the build path to this folder and open a command prompt. (If you know all this stuff, please skip, I just like to type). Type in `cd` (include the space) and then `right-click + paste` the path. Now, type in `cd Scripts`. Finally, do `pip install openpyxl`.

Now, use this code to create an excel for each csv. (Based off of sample code from https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
def writeToExcel(rows, filename):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    for row in rows:
        ws.append(row)

    ws.save(filename)

import csv

rows = []
with open("readfile.csv", "r") as r: 
    reader = csv.reader(r, lineterminator = "\n")

    for row in reader:
        if "SPTU" in row: #"SPTU" Has to be the entire value of the column. Please comment if you want to see if one of the columns CONTAINS "SPTU
            rows.append(row)  

writeToExcel(rows, "insert_name_of_file_here.xlsx")
```

## Replace readfile and writefile with the files you want to read and write to